# Using classes with pointers and files concept My code doesn't work in the 1st case why?

Tags: c++

I was trying file handling with classes whose members we pointers to use the concept in our school project but i don't know why but it doesn't work
I get no output .Why?
PS i am using really old Turbo c++ 3.0 ver compiler

```
#include<fstream.h>
#include<conio.h>
class Q
{
    char*q;
    char*a;
    public:
    void display()
    {
        cout<<q<<'\n'<<a<<'\n';
    }
}obj[28]={"What is the actual color of coca cola","green","Why was donald duck banned from finland","He doesn't wear pants","In which superhero comic will you find the line \"With great power, comes great Responsibility?\"","Spiderman","What is the dot over the letter \"i\" and \"j\" called? ","tittle","What is the world's most popular first name? ","Muhammad"," In Hong Kong, what is a wife, who has been betrayed by her adulterous husband, allowed to do, legally? ",
    "The wife may kill her husband, but with bare hands"," Which big Cat does NOT roar?","Cheetah","Which country released the world’s first 3-D Postage stamp?","Bhutan","What does the term 'piano' mean?","To be played softly","What would you be eating if you ordered LENGUA in Spain?","Tongue","Which animal is known to kill more people than plane crashes? ","Donkeys","Where was the fortune cookie actually invented? ","America","What is the tiny plastic covering of the tip of a shoelace called?","Aglet",
    "In Star Trek, what are Tribbles?","Little furry creatures","The three key combination Ctrl-Alt-Delete can be used to reboot your personal computer or to summon its task manager. Computer geeks sometimes use which expression from the Star Trek TV series to descibe this?","Vulcan Nerve Pinch","What is the land of giants called in Gulliver's Travels?","Brobdingnag","Who lives in a pineapple under the sea? ","Spongebob",
    "Who quoted \"Plato is my friend - Aristotle is my friend - but my greatest friend is truth.\"?","Isaac Newton","How many squares/spaces on a chess board?","64","Japanese three-line verses called Haiku contain how many syllables?","17","Which novel begins \"It is a truth universally acknowledged that a single man in possession of a good fortune must be in want of a wife...\"? ","Pride and Prejudice","What was the carburetor of the first Harley-Davidson, built in the 1903, made of?",
    "Tomato Can","GOLF was abbreviated from originally","Gentlemen Only Ladies Forbidden"," If you were to spell out numbers, how far would you have to go until you would find the letter “A”?","One Thousand","What do bulletproof vests, fire escapes, windshield wipers, and laser printers all have in common?","They are made by women","What is the only food that doesn’t spoil?","Honey","Which cartoon character is famous for the line, \"What's up, Doc?\"?","Bugs Bunny",
    "\"Andale! Andale! Arriba! Arriba!\"  What's the name of this lively cartoon charactor ? ","Speedy gonzales"};
int main()
{
    clrscr();
    ofstream filout("fio.txt");
    for(int q=0;q<28;++q)
        filout.write((char*)&obj[q],sizeof(obj[q]));
    filout.close();
    ifstream filin("fio.txt");
    Q oj;
    while(filin.read((char*)&oj,sizeof(oj)))
        oj.display();//doesn't display content in file
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Notice that `<conio.h>` is Windows specific, and `<fstream.h>` is deprecated. You should `#include` [`<fstream>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/), enable all warnings and debug info in you compiler (e.g. `g++ -Wall -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) ...) and learn how to **use the debugger**. Read also about the [rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29). Add constructors and destructors to `class Q`  which you should name with a more readable name.

Comment: I would also recommend using a newer C++ compiler, preferably one that is nearly [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) compliant, like a recent version (4.8 or 4.9) of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). BTW, you would learn a lot by installing Linux .... (and recent distributions of Linux have GCC 4.8 or 4.9)

Comment: I would but then our school evaluates whatever code we write with that ancient compiler it's school regulations

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
filout.write((char*)&obj[q],sizeof(obj[q]));
```

writes the bytes of the `Q` class into the file. That consists of two pointers, not any readable text, so you won't end up with any text in the file.

To write the strings, use formatted output:

```
filout << obj[q].q << '\n' << obj[q].a << '\n';
```

Reading back is more tricky, since you're using raw pointers to string literals, and there's no easy way to read something compatible from the file. I'd suggest you use `std::string` rather than `char*`; then you can read it back as

```
while (std::getline(filin, oj.q) && std::getline(filin, oj.a)) {
    oj.display();
}
```

This assumes your long-forgotten compiler supports standard(ish) string types. If not, you could bodge it by storing character buffers rather than pointers:

```
char q[MAX_Q_SIZE];
char a[MAX_A_SIZE];
```

where the sizes are large enough for any string that might go in them. This would work with either `filin.getline(q)` (if you have such a thing), or with your code. But beware that this will go horribly wrong if any string is too long.

In any case, I strongly recommend you upgrade to one of this century's compilers; there are few left today who can help you with this ancient dialect.

Comment: our compiler doesn't support string types then what should i do?

Comment: @user3211362: I've added a possible workaround. But you really, really should get a modern compiler; you're wasting your time learning a dysfunctional language that no-one has used for decades.

Comment: it's school regulations

Comment: @user3211362: Then bodge it as I suggest in the last part of the answer. And drop the course if you can - it's a complete waste of time.

Comment: also is there another way to still use the pointers to read from the file? I don't want to use arrays

Comment: @user3211362: You could allocate some memory (hoping the size is large enough), read a line from the file, and use a pointer to that. But then you'll have either memory leaks, or some nasty logic to handle pointers to both allocated memory (which should be freed after use) and string literals (which mustn't be). That's why modern C++ has sensible string types - the alternative is horrible.